# How to get list of product having a specific property id's

Tags: mysql

I have a table having columns 'product_id' and 'property_id'. Some products having both property 20 & 21, some of them only have 20 or 21.

```
product_id   property_id
1            20
1            21
2            20
3            21
3            20
4            21
```

I need to get list of product having both property_id 20 and 21. In here I needed the product list of 1 & 3 like below,

```
product_id
1
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should gives you the correct result.

```
select product_id 
from `xy` 
where property_id in (20,21) 
group by product_id
having count( distinct property_id)=2
```

The the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3a42/14)

Comment: Your query result wrong answer when a product_id has 2 property_id of 20. refer [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83795/6).

Comment: @RagingBull Thanks for the hint. have changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` and `COUNT(distinct property_id)`:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM TableName
WHERE property_id IN (20,21)
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(distinct property_id) = 2
```

**Explanation:**

`IN` checks if `property_id` has values either 20 or 21.

`COUNT (distinct property_id) = 2` verifies having two different values of `property_id`. So, when product 2 has 2 same values in `property_id` like (20,20), it will not be selected.

**Result:**

```
product_id
----------
1
3
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83795/5).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **IN** to check multiple values.

```
Select product_id 
from products 
where property_id in(20,21) 
group by product_id 
having count(property_id) >=2
```

Comment: What if product_id 2 has 2 propert_id values of 20? Like [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83795/12).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM TableName
WHERE `property_id` IN (20,21)
GROUP BY `product_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: What if product_id 2 has 2 propert_id values of 20?

Comment: It would be good to explain your answer :) That way Joe can improve his/her skills and get a better understanding/knowledge of MySQL.